# Most elegant and less error prone way to check ctor parameters

Tags: c++

Given the following simple constructor declaration of a person class:

```
Person(const string& _firstName, const string& _lastName, const string& _id);
```

What way is considered elegant and not error prone to make sure the given parameters are valid?
Say I want to make sure that an object of a type PERSON will contain empty strings even if only ONE of the given arguments is invalid.
I came up with this solution:

```
Person::Person(const string& _firstName, const string& _lastName, const string& _id) {
    if (!isValidName(_firstName) || !isValidName(_lastName)) {
                        firstName = ""; lastName = ""; id = "";
    throw InvalidNameException();
}
if (!isValidID(_id)) {
    firstName = ""; lastName = ""; id = "";
    throw InvalidIDException();
}
firstName = _firstName;
lastName = _lastName;
id = _id;
}
```

The ctor is now way too bloaty to my taste, I thought about writing an init method but I don't really like that solution.

Would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: You need to specify your intention very clearly. If you want to create an "empty" string member variables when all the arguments are invalid, then don't throw exception in the constructor. Objects are not created if exceptions are thrown during construction. Work-around is to delegate construction to a factory, and let the factory throw the exceptions you want to throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest initializing your member variables in the initializer list and then checking whether they're valid.  If they're not, throw an exception.

```
Person::Person(const string& _firstName, const string& _lastName, const string& _id) : 
    firstName( _firstName ),
    lastName( _lastName ),
    id( _id )
{
    if (!isValidName( firstName ) || !isValidName( lastName ) || !isValidID( id ) ) {
        throw InvalidNameException();
}
```

Your member variables are initialized before you get into the constructor body.  The code in the question would initialize the member variables as empty and then initialize them again when they're assigned to.

By throwing an exception, the object is not considered to be constructed anyway, so you don't need to "clear" member variables.  Any member variable that is successfully constructed before your exception is thrown will have its destructor called.  Note, that by throwing if your object throws an exception, it will not have its destructor called (because it was never fully created).

Comment: Thanks, Will use that I guess

Comment: That's also a good solution in this case.  (At any rate, any acceptable solution should initialized in the initializer list.)

Comment: " ... so you don't need to "clear" member variables. ..."  The compiler will do it for you.  As the (partially)-constructed object is taken down again, the memory that was used to store the `string` members must be free.  But the compiler does it automatically.  (Apologies for being so pedantic, and I guess you know already!)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid good point.  I've tried to elaborate on it.  Not sure I can do a better job than [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) though.

Answer (score 3):

Why not wrap the `isValidName` and `isValidId` functions in
functions which either throws or returns the string:

```
std::string
checkedName( std::string const& name )
{
    if ( !isValidName( name ) ) {
        throw InvalidNameException();
    }
    return name;
}

std::string
checkedId( std::string const& id )
{
    if ( !isValidID( id ) ) {
        throw InvalidIDException();
    }
    return id;
}
```

and then:

```
Person::Person( std::string const& firstName,
                std::string const& lastName,
                std::string const& id )
    : myFirstName( checkedName( firstName ) )
    , myLastName( checkedName( lastName ) )
    , myId( checkedId( id ) )
{
}
```

Alternatively (but less readable in my opinion), you can use the
ternary operator:

```
Person::Person( std::string const& firstName,
                std::string const& lastName,
                std::string const& id )
    : myFirstName( isValidName( firstName )
                    ? firstName
                    : throw InvalidNameException() )
    , myLastName( isValidName( lastName )
                    ? lastName
                    : throw InvalidNameException() )
    , myId( isValidID( id )
            ? id
            : throw InvalidIDException() )
{
}
```

Either way, you don't enter into the body of the constructor
unless the strings are valid.

Answer (score 0):

That's hardly bloated. It's only a few lines. But it's always problematic to perform error checking in the constructor.

The best approach is probably to throw an exception just as you have, and have the caller decide how to handle errors.

And I really can't imagine why you must set `_firstName` and `_lastName` to empty strings after you've determined the arguments are invalid.

```
Person::Person(const string& _firstName, const string& _lastName, const string& _id) {
    if (!isValidName(_firstName) || !isValidName(_lastName))
        throw InvalidNameException();
    if (!isValidID(_id))
        throw InvalidIDException();
    firstName = _firstName;
    lastName = _lastName;
    id = _id;
}
```

That's not bloated at all.

Comment: "I really can't imagine why ...".   @Rouki is setting the members `firstName` and `lastName`, not the `_firstNAme`,`_lastName` parameters.  The goal is to ensure the object is in a valid state. --- I think you're saying that `string`s are automatically default-constructed as empty at the start of the constructor, and therefore the explicit `=""` is unnecessary.  Is this what you're saying?

Comment: No, I'm saying the object is not in a valid state anyway if the constructor throws an exception.

Comment: In fact, if you exit the constructor via an exception, the object doesn't exist.  It makes no sense to talk about the validity of its state, since there isn't anything which has a state which can be valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw from a constructor, your object is considered to never have been constructed. There is no point setting the values to empty strings in that case as it would be undefined behavior anyway to somehow try to access the members after throwing an exception from the constructor.

```
Person::Person(const string& _firstName, const string& _lastName, const string& _id)
    : firstName(_firstName), lastName(_lastName), id(_id) {
    if (!isValidName(firstName) || !isValidName(lastName)) throw InvalidNameException();
    if (!isValidID(_id)) throw InvalidIDException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate your concerns.

- Does it make sense to have a `first_name` without a `last_name`?
- Does it make sense to have a `first_name` and a `last_name` without an `id`?
- Does it make sense to have an invalid `first_name`, `last_name`, or `id`?

I believe the answer to all questions is "no". For that reason, I believe that the three entities belong together within an abstract concept called `Identifier` (or similar). This is the case because the checks and guarantees you need to offer are non-trivial.

The class could look as follows:

```
class Identifier {

 public:

  static void ValidateName(const std::string& name) {
    if(name.size() <= 0) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss<<"Invalid name: "<<name<<" (expected non-empty string)";
      throw std::invalid_argument(ss.str());
    }
  }

  static void ValidateId(const std::string& id) {
    if(id.size() != 10) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss<<"Invalid id: "<<id<<" (expected string of length 10)";      
      throw std::invalid_argument(ss.str());
    }
  }

  Identifier(const std::string& first, const std::string& last, const std::string& id)
      : m_first(first),
        m_last(last),
        m_id(id) {
    Identifier::ValidateName(m_first);
    Identifier::ValidateName(m_last);
    Identifier::ValidateId(m_id);
  }

  const std::string& first_name() const {
    return m_first;
  }

  const std::string& last_name() const {
    return m_last;
  }

  const std::string& id() const {
    return m_id;
  }

 private:
  std::string m_first;
  std::string m_last;
  std::string m_id;
};
```

Given the way the class has been designed, it is impossible to create an invalid `Identifier`: one either passes all the tests, or the `Identifier` is never created in the first place.

In addition, notice that there is no way to invalidate an `Identifier` once it has been created; this guarantees that if an instance of `Identifier` exists, it will be valid for its entire existence.

Given that guarantee, you can now create your `Person` instance via a constructor which takes an `Identifier`; the constructor will never throw, and it does not need to make any checks. The `Person` class could look as follows:

```
class Person {
 public:
  Person(const Identifier& identifier) noexcept(true)
      : m_identifier(identifier) { }

  const std::string& first_name() const {
    return m_identifier.first_name();
  }

  const std::string& last_name() const {
    return m_identifier.last_name();
  }

  const std::string& id() const {
    return m_identifier.id();
  }

 private:
  Identifier m_identifier;
};
```

By separating your concerns in this manner:

- You can augment the `Identifier` class with further checks or fields without ever touching the `Person` class: your classes can evolve independently
- You can use `Identifier`s in other places without having to repeat the checks. For example: you could create `Identifier`s and introduce them into a database.

The final code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<stdexcept>

class Identifier {

 public:

  static void ValidateName(const std::string& name) {
    if(name.size() <= 0) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss<<"Invalid name: "<<name<<" (expected non-empty string)";
      throw std::invalid_argument(ss.str());
    }
  }

  static void ValidateId(const std::string& id) {
    if(id.size() != 10) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss<<"Invalid id: "<<id<<" (expected string of length 10)";      
      throw std::invalid_argument(ss.str());
    }
  }

  Identifier(const std::string& first, const std::string& last, const std::string& id)
      : m_first(first),
        m_last(last),
        m_id(id) {
    Identifier::ValidateName(m_first);
    Identifier::ValidateName(m_last);
    Identifier::ValidateId(m_id);
  }

  const std::string& first_name() const {
    return m_first;
  }

  const std::string& last_name() const {
    return m_last;
  }

  const std::string& id() const {
    return m_id;
  }

 private:
  std::string m_first;
  std::string m_last;
  std::string m_id;
};


class Person {
 public:
  Person(const Identifier& identifier) noexcept(true)
      : m_identifier(identifier) { }

  const std::string& first_name() const {
    return m_identifier.first_name();
  }

  const std::string& last_name() const {
    return m_identifier.last_name();
  }

  const std::string& id() const {
    return m_identifier.id();
  }

 private:
  Identifier m_identifier;
};


int main() {
  Identifier id("John", "Doe", "1234567890");

  Person p(id); // cannot throw because id has already been
                // constructed

  std::cout<<p.last_name()<<", "<<p.first_name()<<" Id: "<<p.id()<<std::endl;

  try {
    Identifier id2("Sue", "Smith", "126789");
    Person p2(id2);
    std::cout<<p2.first_name()<<std::endl;
  } catch(const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
  }

  try {
    Identifier id3("", "Smith", "126789");
    Person p3(id3);
    std::cout<<p3.first_name()<<std::endl;
  } catch(const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

which can be compiled using the following command (GCC 4.8.1 on OS X 10.7.4)

```
g++ validated_names.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
```

and produce the following output:

```
./a.out 
Doe, John Id: 1234567890
Invalid id: 126789 (expected string of length 10)
Invalid name:  (expected non-empty string)
```